# Simple while-loop

Tags: c, loops

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
char input;
  while(1){
      printf("Repeat? [Y/N] ");
      scanf("%c", &input);
      if(input=='N' || input=='n'){
          break;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
Repeat? [Y/N] y

Repeat? [Y/N] y

Repeat? [Y/N] n  //Program terminated
```

Output:

```
Repeat? [Y/N] Repeat? [Y/N] y

Repeat? [Y/N] Repeat? [Y/N] y

Repeat? [Y/N] Repeat? [Y/N] n //Program terminated
```

Comment: ... and check the return value for `scanf`

Comment: NB: the idiomatic non-terminating loop in C is `for(;;)` since it avoids constant-value Boolean expressions in `while(1)` which some lints complain about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%c", &input);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &input); //Note the space before %c
```

When you enter a character when the program prompts you to,you enter the character and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key(`\n`).`scanf` reads the character which you have inputted and leaves the newline character(`\n`) in the input stream(`stdin`). As a result,the next time `scanf` is called,it sees the `\n` present in the `stdin` and as it is also a character,`scanf` consumes it and as a result, does not wait for input.

The space before `%c` instructs `scanf` to skip all blanks like newlines and spaces before reading a character.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` is reading `\n` character left behind (on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key) in the input buffer. Just replace your `scanf` with

```
scanf(" %c", &input);  
//     ^A space before %c can skip any number of white-spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

when you press `Enter` after taking y/n , you also take a `Enter` character. for this reason you get `Repeat? [Y/N] Repeat? [Y/N]`

you code is good if you can add just a line `getchar();` like :::

```
int main(void){
char input;
  while(1){
      printf("Repeat? [Y/N] ");
      scanf("%c", &input);
      if(input=='N' || input=='n'){
          break;
      }
      getchar(); // for taking enter
  }
  return 0;
}
```